# How to add values of combobox to database?

Tags: c#, database, combobox

In the collection of my BloodType combobox property. I have 3 values which is O, A and C. But after I choose the option of the value I want, and click submit I get this error.

The parameterized query '(@pFirstName nvarchar(5),@pLastName nvarchar(6),@pContact nvarch' expects the parameter '@pBloodType', which was not supplied.

It will worked if I use a textbox for my bloodtype instead.

For my textbox code which is before.

updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pBloodType", txtpBloodType.Text);

For comboBox code which i am using now.

updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pBloodType", cbpBloodType.SelectedValue);

[image]

Still Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

[image]

```
   public patient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.cbpBloodType = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.cbpBloodType.Items.Add("O");
        this.cbpBloodType.Items.Add("A");
        this.cbpBloodType.Items.Add("C");
    }

    private int AddPatientRecord()
    {
        int result = 0;
        // TO DO: Codes to insert customer record
        //retrieve connection information info from App.config
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
        //STEP 1: Create connection
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        //STEP 2: Create command
        String strCommandText = "INSERT PATIENT(pFirstName, pLastName, pContact, pAddress, pCity, pZip, pNationality, pRace, pIC, pGender, pDOB, pBloodType, pEmail) "
            + " VALUES (@pFirstName,@pLastName,@pContact,@pAddress,@pCity,@pZip,@pNationality, @pRace, @pIC, @pGender, @pDOB, @pBloodType, @pEmail)";

        SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFirstName", txtpFirstName.Text);
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pLastName", txtpLastName.Text);
        //updateCmd.Parameters["@clientid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pContact", txtpContact.Text);
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pAddress", txtpAddress.Text);
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pCity", txtpCity.Text);
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pZip", txtpZip.Text);
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pNationality", txtpNationality.Text);
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pRace", txtpRace.Text);
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIC", txtpIC.Text);
        if (rbMale.Checked)
        {
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pGender", "M");
        }
        else
        {
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pGender", "F");
        }
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDOB", dtppDOB.Value);
        string value = cbpBloodType.SelectedItem == null ? "A" : cbpBloodType.SelectedItem.ToString();
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pBloodType", value);
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pEmail", txtpEmail.Text);
        // STEP 3 open connection and retrieve data by calling ExecuteReader
        myConnect.Open();
        // STEP 4: execute command
        // indicates number of record updated.
        result = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // STEP 5: Close
        myConnect.Close();
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: have you tried using `updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pBloodType", cbpBloodType.SelectedValue.ToString());` ? calling the ToString() method on the value?

Comment: Did you check in the debugger that cbpBloodType and cbpBloodType.SelectedValue exist when running your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to initialize your combobox in code behind :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cb1.Items.Add("O");
    cb1.Items.Add("A");
    cb1.Items.Add("C");
}
```

Then access the data with `cbpBloodType.SelectedItem.ToString();`

```
string value = cbpBloodType.SelectedItem == null ? "A" : cbpBloodType.SelectedItem.ToString();
updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pBloodType", value);
```

Comment: omg this worked, but whatever i clicked, it always gives me A in the datagrid @Plue

Comment: must be this line of code. // Pass default value, for example A
            updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pBloodType", "A"); . how to rewrite it? @Plue

Comment: Change **string bloodtype = cbpBloodType.Text;** to **string bloodtype = cbpBloodType.SelectedValue;**

Comment: I got error when changed to that . Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  @Plue

Comment: After changed to this. string bloodtype = cbpBloodType.SelectedValue.ToString();  this error again.  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  @Plue

Comment: My bad. It sould work with SelectedItem, I updated the answer. The whole problem could come from SelectedItem/SelectedValue, so try without the first part about initializing the combobox.

Comment: I got Still have Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I updated my codes above, can check whether correct? thanks @Plue

Comment: Just use the two last lines of my answer instead of the whole block on bloodtype

Comment: No errors. But I choose C option , and it came out A in datagridview. My current code above @Plue

Comment: Try to remove **this.cbpBloodType = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();**

Answer (score 0):

Mybe cbpBloodType.SelectedValue return null. How are you binding your drop downlist ?

Try this

```
private int AddPatientRecord()
{
    int result = 0;
    // TO DO: Codes to insert customer record
    //retrieve connection information info from App.config
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
    //STEP 1: Create connection
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    //STEP 2: Create command
    String strCommandText = "INSERT PATIENT(pFirstName, pLastName, pContact, pAddress, pCity, pZip, pNationality, pRace, pIC, pGender, pDOB, pBloodType, pEmail) "
        + " VALUES (@pFirstName,@pLastName,@pContact,@pAddress,@pCity,@pZip,@pNationality, @pRace, @pIC, @pGender, @pDOB, @pBloodType, @pEmail)";

    SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFirstName", txtpFirstName.Text);
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pLastName", txtpLastName.Text);
    //updateCmd.Parameters["@clientid"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pContact", txtpContact.Text);
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pAddress", txtpAddress.Text);
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pCity", txtpCity.Text);
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pZip", txtpZip.Text);
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pNationality", txtpNationality.Text);
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pRace", txtpRace.Text);
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIC", txtpIC.Text);
    if (rbMale.Checked)
    {
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pGender", "M");
    }
    else
    {
        updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pGender", "F");
    }
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDOB", dtppDOB.Value);
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cbpBloodType.SelectedValue.ToString()))
    {
      updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pBloodType", cbpBloodType.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
       // Pass default value, for example A
       updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pBloodType","A");
    } 
    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pEmail", txtpEmail.Text);
    // STEP 3 open connection and retrieve data by calling ExecuteReader
    myConnect.Open();
    // STEP 4: execute command
    // indicates number of record updated.
    result = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // STEP 5: Close
    myConnect.Close();
    return result;

}
```

Comment: I got this Object reference not set to an instance of an object by following your code @Mohammad jouhari

Comment: So now instead of writing it in the collection in the property. I write the values in the code is it? @Mohammad jouhari

Comment: Where you got exactly the  Object reference not set to an instance of an object ? Can you Debug It ?

Comment: I thing you have issue with binding the drop down list. Can you share with us that code ?

Comment: At least put your connection to the database in a try catch so you definitely close the connection if the database doesn't like what you send it.

Your code is begging for a database connection to be left open.

Comment: There's a code for that? I just type in the collection proprety of the combobox. @Mohammad jouhari

Comment: I added image. @Mohammad jouhari

Comment: The error is saying cbpBloodType does not reference your drop down list. Does it have this ID : cbpBloodType. Also try to rebuild your application and see what happens.

Comment: Already closed my project. open again, debug, enter values, click submit, still that error. see above. I alr updated to your latest answer codes. Yes the dropdownlist id is cbpBloodType @Mohammad jouhari

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the null exception but in any case I bet you are getting the wrong value from "Selected Value". Assign the variable first then step through it. I bet you might find you are not getting back "A" or "B" but rather something like "System.Windows.Controls..."

try this and see if you get the same error.

```
string bloodtype = cbpBloodType.Text;

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bloodtype))
```

Comment: And when you step through it, is the variable getting assigned properly or is the error happening when you call the AddWithValue?